# Confusion at definition of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I as reading the book **ELEMENTARY DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY, by O'NEILL**, and it's definition of $m$-forms (differential forms) are about functions $\psi:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ generated by the product of $dx_i,\:i\in I$, where $I$ is a $m$-list of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$.

I had a professor that defined alternate forms by this way (in fact, he use only properties as alternation rules, etc, to define the forms, so he proves that this definitions leads to above definition). However, he defines **differential $m$-forms** as functions $\omega:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \wedge^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$, ie, maps vectors (or points) into alternate forms.

I'd like to know if in some sense the two definitions can be similar.

More than that, in some point he wrote this example of $1$-form:

$$\omega:p\mapsto \omega(p)=a_1(p)du_1(p)+a_2(p)du_2(p)$$

Following the definition he gaves, I expect that $\omega (p)$ is an alternate form of degree $1$, ie, a map $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$.

However, I understood $a_1(p)du_1(p)+a_2(p)du_2(p)$ as a point, not a map.

So, I am very confused with this definitions.

Many thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: You should  recall that  $\mathrm du_i$ is none other than the $i$-th projection.

Comment: Well, what do you think $du_1(p)$ means?

Comment: $p$ is a point, $\omega(p)$ is a map $T_p \to \mathbb{R},$ where $T_p$ is the tangent space at $p$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I understood as the projection to i-th coordinate as Bernard say, ie, real valued.

Comment: @md2perpe, sorry, I could not understand as $\omega (p) $ is a map, because I understand $a_i (p) $ anda $du_i (p) $ as real numbers. Are not ? Many thanks!

Comment: @Bernard, right... But I am confused again: if $du_i $ are functions, how O'Neil defines forms as real valued functions? Many thanks once again

Comment: I'm not sure I see very well your objection: the $i$ ptojection maps $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ to $x_i$, and this is a real-valued function.

Comment: $\mathrm{d}u_i(p)$ is *not* a real number; it's a map $T_p \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Bernard, yes. Now I think I understand the book definition, but not yet surely about the professor's definition. If is a real number, why $du_i (p) $ is a map?, I know that for I evaluate $a_idu_i $ at tangent vector $v_p $ I do $a_i(p_i)du_i(v_i)$. So, if I fix $p $ just the projections variate. But why $du_i (p) $ (why $p $ here)? Sorry by my mistakes.

Comment: @md2perpe, I know that for I evaluate $a_idu_i $ at tangent vector $v_p $ I do $a_i(p_i)du_i(v_i)$. So, if I fix $p $ just the projections variate. But why $du_i (p) $ (why $p $ here)? Sorry by my mistakes.

Comment: If what is a real number? Another point: in the exterior product $\bigwedge^n\mathbf R^n$, $\mathbf R^n$ is the *dual space* of the initial $\mathbf R^n$ (they're isomorphic, but it explains why you obtain a form).

Comment: I mean if $du_i (p) $ is a real number, how can be a map. In fact, I think its from tangent plane, so applied in $v $, not $p $. Maybe it can be only a notation? Your second point helps a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: Now I see at a book the notation $(du_i)_p $ and now I could understand this as a function. Thank you, @Bernard.

Comment: Now I see at a book the notation $(du_i)_p $ and now I could understand this as a function. Thank you, @md2perpe.